# shopify cli: theme deploy changed file only

Tags: shopify

using shopify cli, theme deploy will push entire directory, which is slow. I changed a few files and only want push them to shopify.

is there any theme deploy changed files only cmd?

Comment: You can just pass a filename or list of filenames to `theme deploy` and it will upload just those files.

Answer (score 3):

> Without config.yml setup

```
theme deploy --password=[your-api-password] --store=[your-store.myshopify.com] --themeid=[your-theme-id] --env=[environemnt-name] [path-to-file/file-name]
```

EXP:

```
theme deploy --password=AFSJASFLDJ32R424 --store=test.myshopify.com --themeid=3242435425 --env=development assets/test.min.js
```

> With config.yml and environment setup

EXP: Deploy One file

```
theme deploy --env=development assets/test.min.js
```

EXP: Deploy Mutiple Files

```
theme deploy --env=development assets/test.min.js assets/test-2.min.js
```

> config.yml example configurations

```
development:
  password: 1232134124124adfasd32423
  theme_id: "93204212432"
  store: test.myshopify.com
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you use theme kit, you can just use upload command. It is very similar to shopify-cli.

```
theme
Theme Kit is a tool kit for manipulating shopify themes

Theme Kit is a fast and cross platform tool that enables you to build shopify themes with ease.

Complete documentation is available at https://shopify.github.io/themekit/

Usage:
  theme [command]

Available Commands:
  bootstrap   Bootstrap will create theme using Shopify Timber
  configure   Create a configuration file
  deploy      deploy files to shopify
  download    Download one or all of the theme files
  get         Get a theme and config from shopify
  help        Help about any command
  new         New will create theme using Shopify Timber
  open        Open the preview for your store.
  remove      Remove theme file(s) from shopify
  replace     Overwrite theme file(s)
  update      Update Theme kit to the newest version.
  upload      Upload theme file(s) to shopify
  version     Print the version number of Theme Kit
  watch       Watch directory for changes and update remote theme
```

Comment: I dont have a upload command in my theme command. It says unknown command "upload" for "theme". Windows 7, placed theme.exe in program files and added to enviorinement variables. Everything else works just fine.